# success function not occurring before AJAX complete

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to use the jQuery `dialog` box `beforeClose` feature.  I am checking to see if user form data is formatted properly and if not, returning `false` to the `beforeClose`, so the user can re-enter information.

The dialog box code calls the function `submituserupdateform` in the `beforeClose`:

```
.dialog({beforeClose: function () {
  formresult=submituserupdateform($('#myaccountdialog').find('form'));
  if (formresult !="okay"){
    return false;
 }
}})
```

The `submituserupdateform` function checks to see if there was an error in the code:

```
function submituserupdateform($tgt){
  var url='./includes/admin/user/myaccount.php';
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $tgt.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        $("#myaccountdialog").html(data);
        if ($('.error').length){
          var myresult= "notokay";
        } else {
          var myresult ="okay";
        }
      },
      dataType: "html"
    });
   return myresult;
}
```

I have searched, and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call, but I am already setting `myresult` inside my success callback.  I have also tried `ajaxComplete`, `ajaxSuccess`, `.done`.  According to the console, nothing I have tried sets `myresult`; I always end up with an:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: myresult is not defined`

This must be a simple error, please help me if you see my mistake!

Comment: Problem is the `asynchronous` behaviour of ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asynchronous behaviour of ajax will make your function return before the ajax success callback- (*that is what you don't want*)

You can add `async` : `false`

```
 var myresult ="":
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $tgt.serialize(),
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried adding `async:false,` (actually before I submitted the question), and I get entirely the same result.

Comment: You should declare `myresult` before ajax call.. see in my answer

Comment: Sorry, when posting, I made simplification changes.  You answer absolute is correct; it does work!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `myresult` is scoped only to success block. Declare it outside

```
function submituserupdateform($tgt){
  var url='./includes/admin/user/myaccount.php';
  var myresult;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $tgt.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        $("#myaccountdialog").html(data);
        if ($('.error').length){
          myresult= "notokay";
        } else {
          myresult ="okay";
        }
        return myresult;

      },
      dataType: "html"
    });

}
```

And also, as @Mohammad Adil pointed out, there is a possibility that the below code to execute before `formResult` gets assigned with a value from AJAX

```
if (formresult !="okay"){
    return false;
 }
```

In this case, you can go with `async = false` as suggested by him. For your code works always, you should add this too

Comment: This is true, however, it will still be `undefined`.

Comment: Making both changes gives me the same result (formresult == undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var myresult
```

is not globally available  to the function declare it like this

```
function submituserupdateform($tgt){

    var myresult;
```

Comment: Need to add `async: false` also, per the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is asynchronous which means it will post the request and return immediately. Normal script execution will continue while ajax request is running in the background.

What you should do is show some waiting icon while ajax request is running in the background keeping dialog open. Once ajax request returns, handle result using ajax event handlers and depending on the result close the dialog or keep it open showing error msg.

Comment: How can I tell when the AJAX request is completed?