# AJAX ASYNC False vs. True

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a test site here (kdmalikdesign.com/test/rsd/index.html).  I am in the middle of doing a bunch of things with it.  My main concern is right now it does not work unless ASYNC is FALSE which I hear is bad practice?

Now I have determined the reason that async is false is because when i fire the success callback the xml data isn't loaded but when I load a completed callback everything loads fine.  I had to change it to async false to get it to work correctly with the success callback.

Is there a specific way to go about doing this?  Basically what the ajax call is doing is grabbing an xml file and reading through it depending on the filename populating the page with specific data.  I am doing it basically as practice/excercise.

Thank you,
Kamron

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) may be of some help. Your question, as it is now, has no details or code and therefore is unanswerable.

Comment: ASYNC FALSE is only considered bad because it will make the browser wait until the AJAX is complete before proceeding to the next step.  If that makes sense for your application, then it should be no problem.

Comment: It sounds like what you are doing could be done with `async: true` just fine, you most likely aren't handling the logic properly. for example, the success callback should not return data and it should not update any variables that aren't defined directly in the success callback.

Answer (score 5):

Running a synchronous call is usually a malpractice, as you are effectively running a request while losing all the benefits for asynchronicity, when you could be using callbacks to do the same thing in an asynchronous fashion.

`async:false` will cause the `jQuery.ajax()` call to block until it returns. Effectively, in pseudocode, instead of this:

```
function ajax:
   perform request
   callback with results
```

You are doing this:

```
function ajax:
   perform request
   while (no results) wait
   return results
```

This completely blocks the execution of anything else until this is over...which is pretty horrible. The obvious use case for it is running stuff in a `waterfall` pattern: `task 1 -> task 2 -> task 3`, which can happen.

If you can afford to block your browser, still consider using callbacks. They will allow you to keep the rest of your site active and well, while processing stuff. You can easily do this by setting `async:true` and providing a callback with your next step. You may end up in a callback spaghetti, however, and may want to use a library to manage large operations if you have them.

A very good candidate for this hails from Node.JS and is called `async.js`. It is **the** tool for MapReduce stuff, and implements both `waterfall` and `parallel` running models.

**Morale of the story**: async:false can 100% of the time be replaced with a callback.

Comment: There are times that it is necessary.  Please see my question using the `beforeClose` callback; it can't be done.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153314/success-function-not-occurring-before-ajax-complete.

Comment: @SableFoste: I believe there's even an answer to your question in which `async` can still be true. 99% of the time it's unnecessary.

Comment: @SableFoste: `$.when($.ajax({blah})).then(function() {blah; });`. Defining both callbacks this way will mean that they will both be within scope of each other, allowing you to pass `myresult` between them but not return it. Case closed.

Comment: To elaborate: if you're doing a waterfall process, consider `$.when().then()`. If you are returning, consider a callback. If you are triggering something on request termination, consider the waterfall process.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, so how would that work, when you can't chain?  In my referenced question, the callback is set in a dialog box, in the `beforeClose` function.  Trying to chain off the `dialog` function will cause action at the time the box is activated, not just before closing...

Comment: @SableFoste: `beforeClose: function() { if (this.answer !== undefined) return this.answer; // your AJAX call here with as effect to .close() the dialog after setting answer to true/false },`. Done, no async:false, one callback and a clever use of scoping.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to implement asynchronous calls, then you want to organize all logic that is to be done with the resultant data into the .succcess() callback.

> the reason that async is false is because when i fire the success callback the xml data isn't loaded but when I load a completed callback everything loads fine.

That line from your question is a bit confusing because the by definition, the `success callback` is executed once the request completed and any data returned is available.

This is an example of what you cannot do with `async: true`:

```
function ajaxrequest() {
    var someValue;
    $.get('serverFile.php', function(data){
        someValue = data;
    });
    return someValue;
}
```

In that case, the variable `someValue` will be empty when it is returned because the callback you supplied isn't executed *synchronously*, or in-line, with the rest of your code.

To use `async:true` you can organize your code like this:

```
function getData() {
    return $.get('serverFile.php');
}
function alertData() {
    getData().done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
function logData() {
    getData().done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

I have broken it up this way so you can see that it can be helpful to isolate your request methods and have them return the [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object so that multiple other functions can utilize the same request if needed.

Answer (score 0):

async true with same request location makes it critical for data overflowing , specially in database query , it will produce too many connection problem specially if the request is repetitive

and second to nth request will respond longer